# ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using ArrayList inside ArrayList to create a total group of 10 slots divided into another 10 slots, which each slot storing Integers.

**My code:-**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class abc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
        (a.get(i)).add(j,j);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:-**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
        at abc.main(abc.java:18)
```

Can you point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `a.get(i)` fails because you never added anything to `a`.

Comment: Lists of lists are already quite hard to figure hard, so you might want to also consider fixing indentation in your loops

Comment: Despite its name, the `ArrayList` class does _not_ behave exactly like an array; its name was chosen based on how it's implemented.  It implements the `List` interface and begins with zero(0) size, regardless of its initial capacity.  So you need to add items to the list before you can access them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is first add something in a Since you are always reading the i value on the outer list we add a new array list on the outer loop.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class abc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            a.add(new ArrayList<Integer>);
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
            { 
               (a.get(i)).add(j,j);
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: While I agree, I'm still confused as to why `add(j, j)` works. Isn't it in ArrayList of integers?

Comment: @McAdam331 if you read the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)) you see it will add it at that index.

Comment: @brso05 so what value will it have? Why shouldn't it be `add(j)`?

Comment: thanks for that. I had no idea you could add to an index like that, thanks!

Comment: @McAdam331 you are welcome. Also it could be `add(j)` but that unto th OP to what they want to implement.

Answer (score 2):

An arguably more elegant solution does not need `get` and the two-parameter `add`:

```
public class abc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
           ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();
           a.add(inner);
           for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
           {
              inner.add(j);
           }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add an element to the array first before you can access:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
           a.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
           for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
           {
                (a.get(i)).add(j,j);
           }
        }
    }
```

You are trying to access an element the first time `a.get(i)` which does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

This will make your code work:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        a.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); //Add this line
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)               
            a.get(i).add(j); //You should only add 1 integer value
    }
```

**Reason for the additional statement:** You have an arrayList of type `arrayList`. Since your outer `arrayList` is empty, you need to add in an `arrayList` first before you can add an integer value to the inner `arrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

This method eliminates the need for the `get` call.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        for(int i = 0;i < 10; ++i)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            a.add(b);

            for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
            {
                b.add(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```